# Jython 2.5 isdigit

Tags: jes, jython-2.5

I am trying to add an isdigit() to the program so that I can verify what the user enters is valid. This is what I have so far. But when I run it an enter a character, say "f". It crashes and gives me the error which will be posted below the code. Any ideas?

```
def mirrorHorizontal(source):    
    userMirrorPoint = requestString("Enter a mirror point from 0 to halfway through the pitcure.")      #asks user for an input
    while (int(userMirrorPoint) < 0 or int(userMirrorPoint) > (int(getHeight(source) - 1)//2)) or not(userMirrorPoint.isdigit()):
        userMirrorPoint = requestString("Enter a mirror point from 0 to halfway through the pitcure.") 
    height = getHeight(source)
    mirrorPoint = int(userMirrorPoint)
    for x in range(0, getWidth(source)):
        for y in range(0, mirrorPoint):
            topPixel = getPixel(source, x, y)
            bottomPixel = getPixel(source, x, height-y-1)
            color = getColor(topPixel)
            setColor(bottomPixel, color)
```

The error was: f
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 182 of /Volumes/FLASHDRIVE2/College/Spring 16'/Programs - CPS 201/PA5Sikorski.py

Answer (score 0):

isdigit() itself behaves itself in the 2.7.0 jython version I have locally

```
>>> '1'.isdigit()
True
>>> ''.isdigit()
False
>>> 'A'.isdigit()
False
>>> 'A2'.isdigit()
False
>>> '2'.isdigit()
True
>>> '22321'.isdigit()
True
```

Try breaking your big expression up, as typecasting to integers will throw errors for non-numeric strings. This is true across Python versions.

```
>>> int('b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'
>>> int('2')
2
```

You probably want to be careful about the order of the parts of that long expression (this or that or ...). Breaking it up would also make it more readable.